# What is in my empty string?

Tags: null

In my application I want to hide things that don't hold any Information or is NULL.

My column holds only NULL values in DB.

But `IsNullOrEmpty(mycolumn)` returns `false`.

If I check the length it returns 3.

I also checked if it hold 3 blank spaces but that's also not true.

Now I don't know how I can get this boolean question to work so I can hide this fields.

Someone has an idea why `IsNullOrEmpty` doesn't work and why the length is 3?

Comment: Then use a debugger to find out the contents. Also, tag your question with the language.

Comment: which database?

Comment: Can you add tags for which system and/or programming language this is about?

Comment: If I can take a wild guess, you should check if the returned value is `DBNull.Value` instead of `null`. But as I said, just a wild guess.